# Multiple Queries and Easy Output (PDO?)

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

If I have multiple tables, for example `comments` and `user_comments`, how would I query them at once?

typically when i have one table to select I usually do this :

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments");
while($q = $query->fetchObject()){
     $id = $q->id; //getting the id from comments table only
     $text = $q->comment; //getting the comments from comments table only
}
```

This gives me id and comments

Is there a way to query comments and user_comments? and maybe have it go like this

```
$id= $q -> comments -> id;//getting the id from comments table
$text = $q -> comments -> comment;//getting comment from comments table
$user_id = $q -> user_comments -> id;//getting the id from user_comments
$user_text = $q -> user_comments -> comments;//getting the comments from user_comments
```

This will allow me to easily get the values from different tables regardless if it has the same column name or not within each table.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Edit: Test try?

```
$sql = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id=4 UNION SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE id=1");
$q = $sql->fetchObject();
$name = $q->comments->username;
$text = $q->user_comments->comments;
echo $name;
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular exercise forget about PDO and focus on SQL.

You can aggregate two tables with [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_b
```

Comment: I'm not saying not to use it. Do use it. I was just stating that this is an SQL problem and not a PDO. I was trying to make you focus on the SQL part of the problem instead of focusing on PDO.

Comment: can you give a quick example? would I be doing something like `("SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id=$id UNION SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE id=$id")` or something?

Comment: Am I doing it right? I tried but I'm getting a `Call to a member function fetchObject() on a non-object`?